# Не получается увеличить по умолчанию размер текста при печати из формы

Tags: python, pyqt5, шрифты, qtextedit, qprintpreviewdialog

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно при печати документа увеличить размер текста на листе, а то он и на превью и при печати всегда получается очень маленький. Как увеличить размер по умолчанию, я не понимаю.

В данном примере, если вы нажмете на **`File -> Print Preview`** увидите текст в углу, надо увеличить его размер. 
Какие есть другие способы, подскажите, что обычно используется.

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrintDialog, QPrinter, QPrintPreviewDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow,  QAction, \
    QTextEdit, QFontDialog, QColorDialog


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "PyQt5 QToolbar"
        self.top = 200
        self.left = 500
        self.width = 680
        self.height = 480
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.createEditor()
        self.CreateMenu()
        self.show()
    def CreateMenu(self):
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('File')
        editMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Edit')
        helpMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Help')
        printAction = QAction(QIcon("print.png"), "Print", self)
        printAction.triggered.connect(self.printDialog)
        fileMenu.addAction(printAction)
        printPreviewAction = QAction(QIcon("printprev.png"), "Print Preview", self)
        printPreviewAction.triggered.connect(self.printpreviewDialog)
        fileMenu.addAction(printPreviewAction)
        exiteAction = QAction(QIcon("exit.png"), 'Exit', self)
        exiteAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+E")
        exiteAction.triggered.connect(self.exitWindow)
        fileMenu.addAction(exiteAction)
        copyAction = QAction(QIcon("copy.png"), 'Copy', self)
        copyAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+C")
        editMenu.addAction(copyAction)
        saveAction = QAction(QIcon("Save.png"), 'Save', self)
        saveAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
        editMenu.addAction(saveAction)
        pasteAction = QAction(QIcon("Paste.png"), 'Paste', self)
        pasteAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+P")
        editMenu.addAction(pasteAction)
        fontAction = QAction(QIcon("font.png"), "Font", self)
        fontAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+F")
        colorAction = QAction(QIcon("color.png"), "Color", self)
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Toolbar')
        self.toolbar.addAction(copyAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(saveAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(pasteAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(exiteAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(fontAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(colorAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(printAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(printPreviewAction)
    def exitWindow(self):
        self.close()


    def createEditor(self):
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)


    def fontDialog(self):
        font, ok = QFontDialog.getFont()
        if ok:
            self.textEdit.setFont(font)


    def colorDialog(self):
        color = QColorDialog.getColor()
        self.textEdit.setTextColor(color)


    def printDialog(self):
        printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
        dialog = QPrintDialog(printer, self)
        if dialog.exec_() == QPrintDialog.Accepted:
            self.textEdit.print_(printer)


    def printpreviewDialog(self):
        printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
        previewDialog = QPrintPreviewDialog(printer, self)
        previewDialog.paintRequested.connect(self.printPreview)
        previewDialog.exec_()

    def printPreview(self, printer):
        self.textEdit.print_(printer)

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

[image: Пример на картинке]

Пример взят отсюда: https://codeloop.org/pyqt5-creating-print-preview-dialog-qprintpreviewdialog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QTextDocument, QTextCursor, QFont
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrintDialog, QPrinter, QPrintPreviewDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow,  QAction, \
    QTextEdit, QFontDialog, QColorDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, QSizeF


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class TextEditView(QTextEdit):          
    dpi = 72
    doc_width = 8.5 * dpi
    doc_height = 6 * dpi
    font = QFont('Arial', 18)            # !!! попробуйте другие шрифты и размеры

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(readOnly=True)
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(self.doc_width, self.doc_height))

    def build_document(self, data):
        document = QTextDocument()
        self.setDocument(document)
        document.setPageSize(QSizeF(self.doc_width, self.doc_height))
        document.setDefaultFont(self.font)  
        cursor = QTextCursor(document)
        cursor.insertText(f"{data}\n")
        
        return document  
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("im.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 QToolbar")
        self.resize(680, 480)
        
        self.createEditor()
        self.createMenu()
        
        self.textEditView = TextEditView()                          # +++
        
    def createMenu(self):
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('File')
        editMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Edit')
        helpMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Help')
        printAction = QAction(QIcon("print.png"), "Print", self)
        printAction.triggered.connect(self.printDialog)
        fileMenu.addAction(printAction)
        
# printPreviewAction        
        printPreviewAction = QAction(QIcon("printprev.png"), "Print Preview", self)
        printPreviewAction.triggered.connect(self.printpreviewDialog)
        fileMenu.addAction(printPreviewAction)
        
        exiteAction = QAction(QIcon("exit.png"), 'Exit', self)
        exiteAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+E")
        exiteAction.triggered.connect(self.exitWindow)
        fileMenu.addAction(exiteAction)
        copyAction = QAction(QIcon("copy.png"), 'Copy', self)
        copyAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+C")
        editMenu.addAction(copyAction)
        saveAction = QAction(QIcon("Save.png"), 'Save', self)
        saveAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
        editMenu.addAction(saveAction)
        pasteAction = QAction(QIcon("Paste.png"), 'Paste', self)
        pasteAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+P")
        editMenu.addAction(pasteAction)
        fontAction = QAction(QIcon("font.png"), "Font", self)
        fontAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+F")
        colorAction = QAction(QIcon("color.png"), "Color", self)
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Toolbar')
        self.toolbar.addAction(copyAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(saveAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(pasteAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(exiteAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(fontAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(colorAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(printAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(printPreviewAction)
        
    def exitWindow(self):
        self.close()

    def createEditor(self):
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)

    def fontDialog(self):
        font, ok = QFontDialog.getFont()
        if ok:
            self.textEdit.setFont(font)

    def colorDialog(self):
        color = QColorDialog.getColor()
        self.textEdit.setTextColor(color)

    def printDialog(self):
        printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
        dialog = QPrintDialog(printer, self)
        if dialog.exec_() == QPrintDialog.Accepted:
            self.textEdit.print_(printer)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def printpreviewDialog(self):
        previewDialog = QPrintPreviewDialog()
        previewDialog.paintRequested.connect(self.printPreview)  
        previewDialog.exec_()

    def printPreview(self, printer):
        data = self.textEdit.toPlainText()                         # !!!
        document = self.textEditView.build_document(data)          # !!!
        document.print_(printer)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!

Comment: @ДензаЧеловечище пожалуйста